# Numpy combine two 2d martixs

Tags: python, numpy

I am working something like puzzle in python .

What i am trying to do is to cover a piece to map .

For example :

```
 gameMap = np.array([[1 0 0]
                     [0 1 0]
                     [0 1 1]])
 piece = np.array([[0, 1],
                   [1, 1]])
```

How can I put the piece on the map that i can get a result like

```
[[1 1 0]
 [1 2 0]
 [0 1 1]]
```

Or

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [0 2 2]]
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to "add" your piece to the map is to use slicing. The key is selecting a slice of gameMap that is the same shape as the piece.

```
gameMap[0:2, 0:2] += piece
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 0]
 [1 2 0]
 [0 1 1]]
```

OR

```
gameMap[1:3, 1:3] += piece
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [0 2 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that is to pad your second array to the same size as your first array.

```py
print gameMap + np.pad(piece, ((0,1), (0,1)), 'constant')
print gameMap + np.pad(piece, ((1,0), (1,0)), 'constant')
```

While slicing is certainly a preferred (and more performant) way of doing that, using pad can be simpler if you don't want to do it in-place.